# Input check for string validation

Tags: javascript, validation

i am a beginner in javascript and making a input which receive only string
please help me out in this

```
Name:<input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="enter your name" id="myname" required></input>
<button onClick="nCheck()">Check Validitiy</button>
```

```
function nCheck(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myname").value;

    if (x == ""||x == null){
        document.getElementById("nwer").innerHTML = "input is not valid";
        document.getElementById("myname").style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(x)){
        document.getElementById("nwer").innerHTML = "input is number";
        document.getElementById("myname").style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" />`

Comment: As it hasn't been mentioned yet - Never rely on client-side validation only! Remeber to validate the user-input serverside again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regex pattern like

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+"
```

on `input` element.

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" />
```

or you can create a function to validate your input string like this:

```
function validateMyString(){    
    var str = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(str.test(document.getElementById("textboxID").value))
       alert('Valid');
    else
       alert('Numbers not allowed');      
}
```

Comment: i want show error message if invalid character input inside  <p id="message"></p> in form::::              <form name="myForm" onsubmit="myFormValid()" >
Name:<input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="enter your name" id="myname" required></input>
<button onClick="nCheck()">Check Validitiy</button>
<p id="message"></p></form>